# Populating gridview based off a query

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I created a C# application where I called my bindjob method to bind a queries results to the gridview. Now I am working on one for asp and I am getting an error on StringBuilder saying the name space can not be found. How can I fix this so I can use my query to return the results?

```
StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
sqlString.Append("SELECT DISTINCT o.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, d.Time ");
sqlString.Append("FROM [LYNXHQ\\sqlexpress].FRESH_MSS.dbo.Order_Detail o ");
sqlString.Append("FULL OUTER JOIN ");
sqlString.Append("[COMMAND\\sqlexpress].******.dbo.Time d ");
sqlString.Append("ON o.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = d.SalesOrderNumber ");
sqlString.Append("Order by o.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER");
```

C# Bind method that I am basing it off of

```
 StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
 sqlString.Append("SELECT e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName as Name, ");
 sqlString.Append("       jn.JobDescription, SUM(Round(l.TotalMinutes / 60,0)) AS Time ");
 sqlString.Append("  FROM Logins l, JobNumber jn, Employee e");
 sqlString.Append(" WHERE e.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID ");
 sqlString.Append("   AND jn.JobID = l.JobID ");
 sqlString.Append("   AND e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID ");
 sqlString.Append("   GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, jn.JobDescription ");

 DataTable dt = null;

 SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WinhostConnection"].ConnectionString);

  SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID.Value),
                                                         new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate.Date),
                                                         new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate.Date) };

        try
        {
            dt = DBHelper.executeDataTable(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                GridView.DataSource = dt;
            }
            //hide "name" column
            GridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you import System.Text namespace to your project ?

Comment: Do you have a "using System.Text;" statement in your code file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StringBuilder type is the System.Text Namespace; add:

```
using System.Text;
```

to the top of your source file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx